# NetBeans-made jar file won't work

Tags: java, netbeans

So I made this (very simple) program with a swing GUI with NetBeans, and I clicked build to make a jar file. When I run it by double clicking it, it tells me it could not find the main class, which, after checking, I am sure is definitely there. But, when I run it from Command Prompt, it works perfectly. Any easily-determinable reason for this strange behaviour (if you want the source code, I can post it here)?

Comment: `Project` --> `Properties` --> `Run` --> `Main Class`

Comment: And where is the "project" button you speak of?

Comment: [Compiling and Building Projects in the NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Compiling_and_Building_Projects)

Comment: I click on the project, select properties, but there's no run option.

Comment: It should have something like: Sources, Libraries, Build, Compiling, Packaging, Documenting, Run, Application, Web Start, Formatting on the left side of the Project Properties Window.

Comment: @@@@ never mind, that was just me being stupid D:

Comment: Anyway, I got to the main class bit, and selected a class using browse. It still can't find it.

Comment: is there a main(String[] args) method in the main class?

Comment: There is; otherwise the program wouldn't be able to run at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The things that seem to be needed in NetBeans are:

- The project has to be the Main Project (by right clicking on it in the Projects list).
- You have to set the Main Class in the project properties.  (Right click, Properties, Run, Main Class.)

Then when you right click on your project and do a "Clean and Build", a jar will get built into the `dist` subdirectory.

If that fails to fix the problem, here's a longer story...

When you double click a jar file to run it, the operating system acts as if you had typed this from the command line:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

(When you say it works for you from the command line, is this what you're typing?)

At that point, the Java executable looks for a file inside the jar named `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.  And then in the contents of that file, it looks for the value of a property, `Main-Class`.  And finally it looks for the class of that name in your jar and runs its static `main(String[])` method.

So if your jar is failing to run, you can do the following to debug what's going on:

- Clean and rebuild your project in NetBeans.
- Double check that your class(es) are actually in the jar:

  - Start a command prompt
  - `cd` into the `dist` subdirectory of your project.
  - Use a command like `jar tf filename.jar` to list what's in there.
- Double check that the `MANIFEST.MF` file is correct:

  - Again in a command prompt
  - `cd` into the `dist` directory.
  - Use a command like `jar xf filename.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to extract the manifest.
  - Look at the contents of that file (e.g. `type META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`) and make sure `Main-Class` is set to the appropriate class.

If all of the above check out, then double clicking the file *should* work.

Comment: Ok, this is *really* weird. First, yes I am typing something like `java -jar filename.jar` - to be precise, it's `java -jar "C:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Projectname\dist\Projectname.jar"` (am I supposed to have the ""?). Second, everything you listed is correct - in fact, when I type `jar tf filename.jar`, it clearly lists the class it can't find - as `packagename/Classname.class` (it tells me it can't find `packagename.Classname.class`). Everything else is perfect. And it works from the command line, yet not from doubleclicking.

Comment: What is the value of the `Main-Class` property in your `MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: packagename.Classname - everything perfect.

Comment: Yeah some reason netbeans didn't put my main class in Mainifest.mf. I went in their and added it and it worked haha. Thanks csd

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the containing project as the "Main Project"?

Comment: Then follow the other instructions and make sure your project properties have the correct main class selected in the run category.

Comment: It does, and the jar still can't find that class.